# show sharedpreference on preference activity

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm struggling to figure out how to show the preference in the preference activity. I'm simply trying to show the high score and i keep getting the same 345 value show up. I have confirmed in debugging that the new high score is saved . Here is all my code.

preferences.xml

```
<Preference
    android:title="High Score"
    android:selectable="false"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:key="@string/pref_highest_score"/>
```

HighScoreActivity.java

```
public class HighScoreActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new HighScoreFragment()).commit();
}

public static class HighScoreFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    }
}
}
```

strings.xml

```
<!-- High Score settings -->


<string name="pref_highest_score">345</string>
<string name="title_activity_high_score">High Score</string>
```

MainActivity.java

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Assets.highScore = preferences.getInt(context.getString(R.string.pref_highest_score), 1);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.pref_highest_score), currentPoints );
                        editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your preference screen does not actually gets the value of `pref_highest_score`. You should find the preference and call `Preference.setSummary()`. Like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    // Gets the preference defined in XML
    Preference p = findPreference("@string/pref_highest_score");

    // Sets the summary of the preference to the high score
    p.setSummary(
          String.valueOf(preferences.getInt(context.getString(R.string.pref_highest_score), 1))
    );
}
```

where `preferences` is `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`.

And in your XML, specify an id of the preference:

```
<Preference
    android:key="@string/pref_highest_score"
    android:title="High Score"
    android:selectable="false"
    android:defaultValue="0"/>
```

Comment: Almost right. You got me on the right track. I had to make a change to your code. If you will accept it i'll mark your answer. There is no id in preference. I used the key instead. findPreference("@string/pref_highest_score") would get the right preference on the page and then on set summary i had to say String.valueOf() to convert it to string from my int. THANK YOU!

Comment: @DevinPrejean Edited, must've been too used to Kotlin with that `String.valueOf()` part. Glad it helped :)